# Workload Repair failed: `dotnet workload repair - MAUI

Tags: .net, maui, visual-studio-2022

Installed .Net 6 preview 7, tried install dotnet workload for maui at maui-check. facing below issue.

`dotnet workload install --sdk-version 6.0.100-preview.7.21379.14 --no-cache --disable-parallel android-aot ios maccatalyst tvos macos maui wasm-tools --skip-manifest-update --source "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" --source "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/dnceng/public/_packaging/6.0.100-preview.7.21379.14-shipping-1/nuget/v3/index.json" --source "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/azure-public/vside/_packaging/xamarin-impl/nuget/v3/index.json" --source "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/dnceng/public/_packaging/dotnet6/nuget/v3/index.json"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open the terminal, run as administrator.

1. List item

   ```
   $ dotnet workload list
   ```
2. List item

```
$ dotnet workload install maui
```

3. List item

```
$ dotnet workload install maui-android
```

4. List item

```
$ dotnet workload install maui-ios
```

Answer (score -1):

Had it too today. What worked for me is run `dotnet workload install maui` manually. Then rerun `maui-check` to fix the rest of the things.

Comment: After reinstalling workload, project build properly, but faced below error on android deploying. `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '\\..\\AndroidEnvironment.txt'`.

Comment: You might be running into the max path length on Windows. Try placing the folder with the source as close to a root like C:\ so your path is as short as possible and try again. If this answer helped, please don't forget to mark it as an answer :)